# How to make this code work on windows10 machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I was trying to write a chat for a local network (the same with one represented in  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0SLpD7JvZI&t=2s) tutorial). And when executing the code there have occured some mistakes. First of all,when one of the clients stops it's work with ctrl+c combination the command line of this client throws this exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Samsung-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
32\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\Samsung-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
32\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "chat.py", line 39, in send_message
self.s.send(bytes(input(""),'utf-8'))
EOFError
```

and the client still works whithout exiting the program. The work of this client stops only when another client connects to the server. Then,another problem is that server crashes with that exception when one of the clients closes his widow with chat.

```
   Exception in thread Thread-2:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Samsung-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
   32\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
   File "C:\Users\Samsung-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
   32\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "chat.py", line 14, in handler
   data=c.recv(1024)
   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]
```

And here is the code

```
import socket 
import threading 
import sys

class Server:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connections = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.s.bind(('192.168.56.1',9090))
        self.s.listen(1)

    def handler(self,c,a):
        while True:
            data=c.recv(1024)
            for connection in self.connections:
                connection.send(data)
            if not data:
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                print(str(a[0])+':'+str(a[1]),'disconnected')

                break

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c,a =self.s.accept()
            cThread=threading.Thread(target=self.handler,args=(c,a))
            cThread.daemon=True
            cThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)
            print(str(a[0])+':'+str(a[1]),'connected')
class Client:

    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send_message(self):
        while True:
            self.s.send(bytes(input(""),'utf-8'))

    def __init__(self,addr):
        self.s.connect((addr,9090))

        iThread=threading.Thread(target=self.send_message)
        iThread.daemon=True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            data=self.s.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(str(data,'utf-8'))
if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    client=Client(sys.argv[1])
else:
    server=Server()
    server.run()
```

How can I change this code to make it work on windows 10 without such mistakes (or any other mistakes))?